# How to validate android device token

Tags: jakarta-ee, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

I am new in push notification services. I want to remove invalid android device token from server database. Any one know how can validate token using gcm service.
In advance thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to send a GCM message to the GCM connection server you are using (either HTTP or CCS) containing the registration token (that's what they call it now, not device token) you wish to validate. If it's invalid, you'll get an error response that will let you know that.

Comment: There is need send push to know that registration token is expire or not. But my requirement is to detect registration token valid or not without send push. I know if i send push with invalid registration token i will get error message like "UN-register token". I want to detect it without send push.

Comment: @AnujDhiman You can send a message with the `dry_run` parameter set to true. It will give you a response without actually sending the message to the device.

Comment: i used gcm-server-1.0.2.jar for sending push but there is no dry_run parameter . I have download source code this library and read message class . Can u help me how to set dry_run parameter to true.

Comment: @AnujDhiman If it's not in the gcm-server JAR, you'll have to implement the HTTP request to GCM by yourself (or change the source code of the library). You can read about it here - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref.

Comment: I have follow this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http and solve the issue